# Unity: Script for Input System UI Input Module not appearing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the new input system and some buttons for my game. However, when I try to click on a button, I get a message from the Console saying that the script is missing. I cannot change it as the option is locked.
Does anybody know why am I getting this? I have watched several videos and all of them have a script there. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDCwG.png)

I have also tried to add the Standalone Input System as a component, and I still get the same result.

Comment: in your project settings what is the setting for `Player -> Other Settings -> Active Input Handling`?